# run function cpp in qml using thread

Tags: multithreading, qml

I want to run a function that uses thread ، I'll run when the program stops a few seconds . What is the reason for this stop? In C #, to avoid this stop before I used a thread .
Please do guide me
thanks

Comment: [This should be a good starting point](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html).

Comment: if possible Put a sample code thanks